# External Functions and Parameter Size Limitation (C)

Tags: c

I am very much stuck in the following issue. Any help is very much appreciated!

Basically I have a program wich contains an array of structs and I am getting a segmentation error when I call an external function. The error only happens when I have more than 170 items on the array being passed.

Nothing on the function is processed. The program stops exactly when accessing the function.

Is there a limit for the size of the parameters that are passed to external functions?

Main.c

```
struct ratingObj {
    int uid;
    int mid;
    double rating;
};

void  *FunctionLib;     /*  Handle to shared lib file   */
void (*Function)();     /*  Pointer to loaded routine   */
const char *dlError;        /*  Pointer to error string */

int main( int argc, char * argv[]){
// ... some code ...
    asprintf(&query, "select mid, rating "
                     "from %s "
                     "where uid=%d "
                     "order by rand()", itable, uid);
    if (mysql_query(conn2, query)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn2));
        exit(1);
    }
    res2 = mysql_store_result(conn2);
    int movieCount = mysql_num_rows(res2);
    // withhold is a variable that defines a percentage of the entries 
    // to be used for calculations (generally 20%)
    int listSize = round((movieCount * ((double)withhold/100)));
    struct ratingObj moviesToRate[listSize];
    int mvCount = 0;
    int count =0;
    while ((row2 = mysql_fetch_row(res2)) != NULL){
        if(count<(movieCount-listSize)){
            // adds to another table
        }else{
            moviesToRate[mvCount].uid = uid;
            moviesToRate[mvCount].mid = atoi(row2[0]);
            moviesToRate[mvCount].rating = 0.0;

            mvCount++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    // ... more code ...
    FunctionLib = dlopen("library.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    dlError = dlerror();
    if( dlError ) exit(1);
    Function = dlsym( FunctionLib, "getResults");
    dlError = dlerror();
    (*Function)( moviesToRate, listSize );
// .. more code
}
```

library.c

```
struct ratingObj {
    int uid;
    int mid;
    double rating;
};

typedef struct ratingObj ratingObj;

void getResults(struct ratingObj *moviesToRate, int listSize);

void getResults(struct ratingObj *moviesToRate, int listSize){
// ... more code
}
```

Comment: Can you add in your post the part where you come up with listSize?Also the part you populate the array before calling `getResults`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us what `listsize` is, but I suppose it is a variable and not a constant.

What you are using are variable length arrays, VLA. These are a bit dangerous if they are too large since they usually allocated on the stack.

To work around that you can allocate such a beast dynamically

```
struct ratingObj (*movies)[listSize] = malloc(sizeof(*movies));
// ...
free(movies);
```

You'd then have in mind though that `movies` then is a pointer to array, so you have to reference with one `*` more than before.

Another, more classical C version would be

```
struct ratingObj * movies = malloc(sizeof(*movies)*listsize);
// ...
free(movies);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid malloc for silly coding taste. It seems I will have to pay for it... You are right listSize is a variable.

Comment: malloc is painful but because I knew the size of the arrays from the begining it made it easier (i.e. no need for realloc). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are likely blowing up the stack. Move the array to outside of the function, i.e. from `auto` to `static` land.

Another option is that the `// ... more code - array gets populated...` part is corrupting the stack.

#### Edit 0:

After you posted more code - you are using [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) variable sized array on the stack - `Bad IdeaTM`. Think what happens when your data set grows to thousands, or millions, of records. Switch to dynamic memory allocation, see [`malloc(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html).

Comment: He is just passing 2K.It this too big alocation for the stack?170*(4+4+8)=2720 bytes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give more details please (a link maybe)? I am not sure I get it.

Comment: Thanks again. I have modified all the code to use malloc. There were other related issues (wrong indexing) that I found out later and fixed too. Thanks for your support. @JensGudsted got it right straight away.